# Bootstrap: Custom sort ascending and descending

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make a custom sorter for a bootstrap table. The normal sort function doesnt work, when I want to sort values like:
1.000.000,00; 1.100.000,00; 800.000,00; 900.000,00

It sorts them like this:
900.000,00; 800.000,00; 1.000.000,00; 1.100.000,00

I wrote a custom function and used data-sorter to call it.
The function is being called but i only receive 2 parameters, a and b, bootstrap is not telling me if i should be sorting asc or desc right now.
I tried writing a function with 3 parameters and got passed the row as additional parameter, I dont see, how that helps me.

Html:

```html
<table id="milestones" class="table table-bordered w-75 ml-auto mr-auto mt-0 mb-0" data-toggle="table">
    <thead class="thead-light">
        <tr>
            <th data-sortable="true">Year</th>
            <th data-sortable="true">Business</th>
            <th data-sortable="true">Name</th>
            <th data-sortable="true" data-sorter="moneySorter">Money</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
```

Javascript:

```
function moneySorter(a, b) {
    if (a > b) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I have found a really ugly solution by stopping the time between the calls to the function and then sorting it the other way around if x miliseconds passed, but strangly it requires a double click to work:

```
    var lastSort = 0;
    var status = 0;

    function moneySorter(a, b) {
        if (new Date().getTime() > lastSort + 20) {
            console.log(status);
            if (status < 3) {
                status = status * 1 + 1;
            } else {
                status = 0;
            }
        }
        lastSort = new Date().getTime();

        if (status < 2) {
            if (a > b) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        } else {
            if (a < b) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

I also discovered, that my function is called every click on the sorting symbol but my result is only accepted every second time. That's why i am using the 4 states:

State 0: 1st click, result is ignored, asc

State 1: 2nd click, result is accepted, asc

State 2: 3rd click, result is ignored, now desc

State 3: 4th click, result is accepted, desc

My current code is really bad and only working if the user double clicks. It would be nice if somebody has an idea how to get passed a parameter telling me if to sort up or down.

Thank you!